# How to define an outgoing event from subclassed UIView so any delegate in UIViewController can be called

Tags: ios, events, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have derived my own View class from UIView that handles gestures and drawing itself.
I use Interface Builder to place several instances of it on a View.

On certain events, I want to call several delegates in the UIViewController, just like an UIButton::onTouchUpInside event. I don't want to set up an interface protocol and connect an IBOutled id instance, like in (1).

I was looking all around documentation and also stack overflow, but I haven't found any clue about the syntax.

So, what is the syntax for that with Xcode 4.4 (just updated)?
Deployment Target will be IOS >=5.0 because of the custom properties I already use.

[EDIT]
Subclassing from UIControl does give indeed access to the standard UI events like TouchUpInside, but is it possible to add custom named events like "onSomethingElse"?

(1) [Events for custom UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906762/events-for-custom-uiview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure exactly what you want from this view, but if you want to handle things like UIButton::onTouchUpInside event, then maybe you should look into subclassing UIControl instead of UIView. It gives you access to events, just like UIButton.

Comment: Ok, I did that and now I have the usual events. I also can connect them in Interface Builder. Is it correct to call the connected actions by "  [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];"?

Comment: @Zuppa This fires the event in the control, resulting in the IBAction registered by the controller getting called. I'm guessing this is what you want. Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery, works so far. Any idea about completely custom events like "onDraggedOnRedField" and "onDraggedOnGreenField"?

Answer (score 0):

If you post a NSNotification of whatever custom event you define, you can have multiple listeners registered with the NSNotificationCenter to respond to the event.

You can see details by looking for `addObserver:selector:name:object:` and `postNotificationName:object:`.

Comment: I actually wanted to use Interface Builder to connect my view with the selector, not programmatically.